# R: Splitting a Time Series into custom seasons

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, openair

I have a time Series DataFrame:

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/elaxfuvqyip1eq8/SampleDF.csv?dl=0][1]

My intention is to divide this DataFrame into different seasons according to:

1. **winter**: Dec Jan Feb
2. **Pre-monsoon**: Mar Apr May Jun15 (i.e. till 15th of June)
3. **Monsoon**: 15Jun Jul Aug Sep (i.e. from 15th of June)
4. **Post-monsoon**: Oct Nov.

I tried using `openair` package function

`selectByDate()`

But no luck yet.
Being novice in R.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the `lubridate` package which makes working with date/time a bit easier.

For your problem, I guess you can use `sapply`:

```r
df["season"] = sapply(df["date"], assign_season)
```

where, `assign_season`:

```r
assign_season <- function(date){
    # return a season based on date 

}
```

once you have seasons, then you can divide the dataframe easily:

```r
winter = subset(df, season == "winter")
# and so on
```

Sorry, I have to rush now, but can come back and finish this, if someone else hasn't answered already.

EDIT:

So, R does have a built in function `cut`, that can work on dates and split a vector based on date ranges.

For your data, I did this like so:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df = read.csv('SampleDF.csv')

## reformat date into POSIXct
df <- df %>%
         mutate(date_reformat = as.POSIXct(date(mdy_hm(date))))

## define breaks & labels
breaks = c("2014-12-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-06-15", "2015-10-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-06-15", "2016-10-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-03-01")
labels = c("winter", "pre_monsoon", "monsoon", "post_monsoon", "winter", "pre_monsoon", "monsoon", "post_monsoon", "winter")
df["season"] = cut(df$date_reformat, breaks=as.POSIXct(breaks), labels=labels)

splits = list()

for (s in c("winter", "pre_monsoon", "monsoon", "post_monsoon")){
  splits[[s]] = subset(df, season == s)[c("date", "value")]
}
```

Now, the splits list should have all the data you need

Comment: Dear `@asifzuba` thanks a lot. Let me try with it.

Comment: hi @Peshal1067 , can you have a look at the edited answer. It should have all that you need! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete solution @asifzuba . Finally solved. Highly appreciated!